# Visual Studio 2012 Colorizer and IntelliSense for the NVelocity language

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nvelocity

The [CVSI (Castle Visual Studio Integration)](http://www.jonorossi.com/projects/cvsi/) (which was available up to VS2010) was a good solution for handling NVelocity content files. There is no version for VS2012. Is there any other Extension for VS2012 out there to handle NVelocity content? Adding .vm extension support via the HTML editor is a temporary solution to provide some support for formatting the HTML in the content...but not the NVelocity code.

Comment: Fork https://github.com/jonorossi/cvsi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually upgraded CVSI for Visual Studio 2012 towards the end of last year, however I never published it because I couldn't work out how to make a single .vsix support both VS2010 and VS2012 so I could upload it to the Visual Studio Gallery.

I'm happy to email you (or upload) a preview .vsix that you can try out and let me know how you go. Since there is still interest in CVSI, I'll try to find some time over the next few weeks to get the updated version up on the gallery.

**Edit 2014-05-25:** I've released 0.5.0 with support for Visual Studio 2012 and 2013, you can download them here: http://jonorossi.com/projects/cvsi/

Comment: That would be awesome! I had been using your Extension for the past year prior to migrating to VS2012 and it was a giant help.

Comment: I couldn't find an email address so I've just uploaded it to SkyDrive, https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=4E7250B450E544AC!129. Let me know if you have any problems.

Comment: Thank you Jonathon! I will give it a spin.

Comment: Discovered something...if you have ReSharper (version confirmed on was 7.1.1) installed prior to installing CVSI for Visual Studio 2012 the color coding does not show up for .vm files. If you uninstall/re-install ReSharper the color coding will work. You might need to reboot or log out/in to complete the process for VS (after the ReSharper re-install I closed all instances of VS and re-opened but no color coding...however when I logged out of Windows and back in it started working).

Comment: I also noticed that VS2012 seems to aggressively cache fonts and colors, so if you don't get any coloring but the intellisense works then follow the details in the following link to reset the cache which we've had to workaround a few times in the past. I'm still none the wiser on how this should be handled properly.
https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups=#!topic/castle-project-devel/MhUa0R4U9GU

Comment: I use a dark VS 2010 theme. Is there a CSVI option that will respect my theme choice?

Comment: @Kevin you should be able to change the colours CVSI uses in the `Fonts and Colors` settings tab. If the "NVelocity" prefixed items don't show up, follow the link in my comment here on Feb 13 to reset the cache.